# Is there a practical way of setting a background colour or halo for text marks in Vega-Lite?

Tags: vega-lite

I have made a gantt chart similar to this https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/bar_gantt.html but with an additional text layer for data labels. In order to fit with my company's style guide I have only a limited number of colours to choose from, all of which go horribly with black, and using white causes some of the marks to be hidden when they overlap the bar. Is there a way of specifying a background colour for text marks to address this?

I have tried looking through all the Vega-Lite documentation and the github issues page. Closest previous result I can come up with is this: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/pull/1912 which suggests the functionality has been removed?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.json",
  "width": 400,
  "height": 150,
  "data":{
    "values": [
 {
   "rig_name": "Rig 1",
   "contract_start_date": "2018-01-15 00:00:00 UTC",
   "contract_end_date": "2019-03-15 00:00:00 UTC",
   "dayrate": 300000
 },
 {
   "rig_name": "Rig 1",
   "contract_start_date": "2019-05-16 00:00:00 UTC",
   "contract_end_date": "2019-06-15 00:00:00 UTC",
   "dayrate": 30000
 },
 {
   "rig_name": "Rig 2",
   "contract_start_date": "2018-04-21 00:00:00 UTC",
   "contract_end_date": "2019-04-20 00:00:00 UTC",
   "dayrate": 300000
 },
 {
   "rig_name": "Rig 2",
   "contract_start_date": "2019-04-21 00:00:00 UTC",
   "contract_end_date": "2019-10-20 00:00:00 UTC",
   "dayrate": 300000
 }
]
  },
  "transform": [
        {
          "calculate": "datum.contract_start_date + ((datum.contract_end_date - datum.contract_start_date) / 2)",
          "as": "contract_mid_date"
        }
      ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar"
      },
      "selection": {
        "grid": {
        "type": "interval", 
        "bind": "scales",
        "zoom": "wheel!"
        }
      },
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "rig_name",
          "type": "ordinal",
          "title": ""
        },
        "x": {
          "field": "contract_start_date", 
          "title": "Date",
          "type": "temporal",
          "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate",
          "scale": {
            "domain": ["2018-06-01", "2020-06-01"]
          },
          "axis": {
            "format": "%b %Y",
            "orient": "top"
          }
        },
        "x2": {
        "field": "contract_end_date"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "rig_name",
          "type": "ordinal"
        },
        "x": {
          "field": "contract_mid_date", 
          "title": "Date",
          "type": "temporal",
          "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate"
        },
        "x2": {
          "field": "contract_end_date"
        },
        "text": {
          "field": "dayrate",
          "type": "nominal"
        },
        "color": {
          "value": "white"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {
    "scale": {"rangeStep":50}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/pull/1912 is for heatmap background, so it's probably not really for your use case.  We have an open issue https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/1820, which would make this really easy.

For now, you would have to manually add a rect layer and manually adjust the start and end position of the rect to match text length, which is honestly not ideal.

Comment: unfortunately, this issue looks like closed with a recommendation of "using reactive geometry" instead of some native implementation.